# Visual Studio 15 - Move Namespace Hierarchy bar

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, customization

In Visual Studio 2015, is there a way to move the hierarchy bar (for lack of a known term, [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB8KU.png)) to the bottom of the editor or turn it off entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called **Navigation bar**. You can turn it off in Options - Text Editor - C#.

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me.